# Serial Port Communication problem while using UART

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, uart, com0com

I'm trying to send and receive data between a board (Dialog DA14531) and a simulation application of a temperature sensor.

- I can easily send and receive data between the board and my computer, using Termite for instance.
- By using Com0Com, I can receive the data sent from the sensor simulator in Termite as well.
  However; I can't directly send data between this simulator and my board. I'm using Advanced Serial Port Monitor application and while the simulator states that the connection has been established, there seem to be nothing going on with this port.
  Does someone have any idea about what might have caused the problem and how should I proceed for debugging?

Comment: Probable reason:1.Physical layer is not connected between two devices properly. or 2. Baudrate mismatch

Answer (score 0):

So, I've figured out a new way to fix the issue:

- Created a pair of virtual ports by using Com0COM.
- Connected the simulator to one of these ports and Termite to the other one.
- Connected the board to the system.
- Used port forwarding in Termite to send the received data to the board.
  This way, I can also monitor the data traffic between the board and the simulator.